# Seeking atmospheric WMS data for South America and Brazil

Tags: wms, data, noaa, brazil, south-america

I'm working in a environmental project in Brazil and I need to create, if possible, a map service to show atmospheric conditions.

I'm looking for a WMS source to show cloud and another atmospheric data in Brazil. Something similar to the map from this link:

https://www.nesdis.noaa.gov/imagery/interactive-maps/the-world-real-time

Does anyone know a WMS that can provide me with this data?

Comment: If it’s an open data service that you seek then I think the place to ask is the [opendata.se] Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 1):

> Does anyone know a WMS that can provide me with this data?

A WMS doesn't provide data, only a representation of it, sometimes queryable. If you want to access data you'd need a WFS/WCS or other data API.